# Wordpress 'twentyseventeen' theme filters declarations

Tags: php, wordpress

I've just started learning Wordpress and going through standard/default themes. If i have understood filters idea correctly, before we can apply them we need to add callback functions via `add_filter($hook, $callback, $args)`. However looking at the 'twentyseventeen' theme i can't see those declaration for `twentyseventeen_starter_content` and it is used then with: `$starter_content = apply_filters( 'twentyseventeen_starter_content', $starter_content );` (file functions.php) and `twentyseventeen_front_page_sections` - `$num_sections = apply_filters( 'twentyseventeen_front_page_sections', 4 );` (file front-page.php). What am i missing and how does it work without setting callback functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply_filters` runs all the callbacks attached to it by `add_filter` to the same hook/tag. If there are no callbacks attached to that hook/tag it returns the second parameter (which is the value beng filtered) of the `apply_filters`.  Therefore `apply_filters( 'twentyseventeen_front_page_sections', 4 );` will return **4** if there are no `add_filter('twentyseventeen_front_page_sections', 'callbackfunc');`. Else it will return the result of the add_filter callback with the highest priority after going through all callbacks.

Priorities are set in the `add_filter` as the third parameter.

I don't know if this what you were looking for but i thought it might give you a better understanding.